# Impact of Changing Server System Date to one Month Back(Win Server 2008 R2)

Tags: date, networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an application hosted on a dedicated Win Server 2008 R2.
The customer need past 3 months data to be entered into the application.We have only one method and that is setting the Server System Date to 3 months back data, till all the users completes updating the past data.

So my question is does setting the System Date to past date have any kind of impact in normal functioning of server or the network it's part of.

Please advice...

Answer (score 1):

The server might automatically try to correct its time back to current time.  If this server is apart of AD then there could be some issues.  If it is apart of AD and is a GC then users might not be able to authenticate do to a time discrepancy.  Updates via Windows Updates will also not work until the time is corrected.  If this is the only way I would suggest getting it done as quickly as possible and setting the time back.